# launchd start times seem to be creeping later and later

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm new to launchd, so it's possible I did something incorrectly. I have a script that I intend to run hourly. To that end, I created a plist file with the following entry in order to make that happen:

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>3600</integer>
```

It's running approximately hourly, but it's sort of acting like the time interval is meant to be from complete time of one instance to start time of the next. I say this because start times are getting steadily later. Here's a listing:

```
Aug 30 21:00:43 2016 2016083021 
Aug 30 22:00:45 2016 2016083022 
Aug 30 23:00:49 2016 2016083023
Aug 31 00:00:51 2016 2016083100
Aug 31 01:00:53 2016 2016083101
Aug 31 02:00:54 2016 2016083102
Aug 31 03:00:56 2016 2016083103 
Aug 31 04:00:57 2016 2016083104
Aug 31 05:00:58 2016 2016083105
Aug 31 06:01:00 2016 2016083106
Aug 31 07:01:02 2016 2016083107
Aug 31 08:01:06 2016 2016083108
Aug 31 09:01:11 2016 2016083109
Aug 31 10:01:17 2016 2016083110
Aug 31 11:01:22 2016 2016083111
Aug 31 12:01:27 2016 2016083112
Aug 31 13:01:32 2016 2016083113
Aug 31 14:01:38 2016 2016083114
Aug 31 15:01:43 2016 2016083115
Aug 31 16:01:51 2016 2016083116
Aug 31 17:01:56 2016 2016083117
Aug 31 18:02:02 2016 2016083118
```

Is this a known feature of launchd? Should I be setting up my start interval differently?

Comment: Well, after looking around, it looks like what I really should be using is `StartCalendarInterval` instead of `StartInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartInterval` repeats at approximately the number of seconds indicated. `StartCalendarInterval` repeats at the specified calendar/clock time.

Here is what I wound up using:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

There is still some random delay, but it's after the time specified rather than after the elapsed period, so it doesn't gradually keep getting later.

```
Sep  1 21:00:08 2016 2016090121
Sep  1 22:00:04 2016 2016090122
Sep  1 23:00:04 2016 2016090123
Sep  2 00:00:02 2016 2016090200
Sep  2 01:00:06 2016 2016090201
Sep  2 02:00:08 2016 2016090202
Sep  2 03:00:02 2016 2016090203
Sep  2 04:00:06 2016 2016090204
Sep  2 05:00:02 2016 2016090205
Sep  2 06:00:02 2016 2016090206
Sep  2 07:00:07 2016 2016090207
Sep  2 08:00:03 2016 2016090208
Sep  2 09:00:04 2016 2016090209
Sep  2 10:00:09 2016 2016090210
Sep  2 11:00:11 2016 2016090211
Sep  2 12:00:11 2016 2016090212
Sep  2 13:00:08 2016 2016090213
Sep  2 14:00:10 2016 2016090214
Sep  2 15:00:10 2016 2016090215
Sep  2 16:00:11 2016 2016090216
Sep  2 17:00:11 2016 2016090217
Sep  2 18:00:14 2016 2016090218
Sep  2 19:00:09 2016 2016090219
Sep  2 20:00:07 2016 2016090220
```